# Django Installation on Windows 10

Tags: python, django

I'm a newbie when it comes to Django framework, just want to ask if what drive is it recommended to install Django, should I follow YT vids that installs on desktop or should I put it in more specific path. Thanks

As for now I haven't tried to install it, I'm still gathering opinions from experts to reduce flaws and errors in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

As the official [documentation advises](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/windows/), it's recommended to install django in a virtual environment in the folder where you want to keep your project, especially if you are not an expert and don't know what to do otherwise. If you don't know what a virtual environment is, I recommend that you consult the [official python documentation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

Answer (score 0):

you can check the django official documentation to get an idea on how to get started.

1. first make sure to have the latest version of python installed.
2. install django from the commandline using `pip install Django`

**Note about virtual environments**: if you are completely new to programming and not sure about how to install django in a virtual environment, you can just install it globally, then eventually as you learn how to, start using virtual environments

here are some useful references:

- [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/install/)
- [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_install_django.php)
- [geekforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-introduction-and-installation/)
- you can definitely find some useful youtube videos, but i don't know any.